# ListRows.Add() gives error when list is filtered

Tags: excel, listobject, vba

I have the following code (for Excel 2007 and newer) that is called from a Worksheet_Change event:

```
Sub InsertRow(Movs As ListObject, currentRow As ListRow)
    Dim newRow As ListRow

    Set newRow = Movs.ListRows.Add(currentRow.index + 1) 'gives error when list is filtered

    ' below is my custom code, but you don't need to understand it to answer the question:
    Range("xMaxID") = Range("xMaxID") + 1
    newRow.Range.Columns(colID) = Range("xMaxID")
    CopyRow Movs, currentRow, newRow

End Sub
```

Basically, when the user makes certain changes in an Excel table, a new Row is created under the current row, with a copy of the data, with a couple of ID fields cross-referencing both rows so I know they are related.

This works fine, but I get this error on ListRows.Add when the list is filtered and the event occurs:

`Run-time error 1004: cannot shift cells in a filtered range or table`

I understand the error, and I think I could work around it, removing the filter first; but that's rude to the user, forces them to redo the filter afterwards (which can be complex).

What could be an **elegant** solution to this issue? Is it possible to somehow get the new row created but keep (or automatically reinstate) the filter?

Comment: I think your options are much the same as if you tried it manually - i.e. insert a new sheet row, rather than table row, or just add the row to the bottom.

Comment: Thanks. Adding at the bottom is not an option, but with your other tip I was able to get to a solution - I posted it as an answer to my own question. Of course, I will upvote you here (and elsewhere).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to a tip from Rory, a good answer is **insert an entire sheet row, not just a Listrow**.

Here is the updated code:

```
Sub InsertRow(Movs As ListObject, currentRow As ListRow)
    Dim newRow As ListRow

    Movs.Range.Worksheet.Rows(currentRow.Range.Row + 1).Insert
    Set newRow = Movs.ListRows(currentRow.index + 1)

    '(...) rest of sub omitted

End Sub
```

Watch out for two possible problems:

1. when adding new rows in filtered lists, your new row **might not be visible** if it doesn't match the filter criteria.
2. If you have anything on either side of your ListRow, the new sheet row might break it.